# How do i fix 'Loss is nan, stopping training'?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, image-recognition

I've been trying to run an specific proyect (https://github.com/nicolaihaeni/MinneApple) where i have to run a training model for fruit counting/detection with image recognition.
I tried running the code given for it many times but i still get the following error after running `python train_rcnn.py --data_path data --model frcnn --epochs 50 --output-dir data/train/train_results`:

```
Start training
Epoch: [0]  [ 0/20]  eta: 0:04:09  lr: 0.001072  loss: 3.8136 (3.8136)  loss_classifier: 0.9121 (0.9121)  loss_box_reg: 0.6673 (0.6673)  loss_objectness: 2.0488 (2.0488)  loss_rpn_box_reg: 0.1854 (0.1854)  time: 12.4626  data: 4.8800  max mem: 3233
Loss is nan, stopping training
{'loss_classifier': tensor(nan, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLossBackward0>), 'loss_box_reg': tensor(nan, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<DivBackward0>), 'loss_objectness': tensor(nan, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<BinaryCrossEntropyWithLogitsBackward0>), 'loss_rpn_box_reg': tensor(nan, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<DivBackward0>)}

An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
```

The images and masks database can be found here (if someone wants to reproduce this): https://conservancy.umn.edu/handle/11299/206575

I'll keep digging while I wait for answers, thank you in advance.

P.D.: The full traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

SystemExit                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-11-d923a94e9af1> in <module>
      4 start_time = time.time()
      5 for epoch in range(epochs):
----> 6     train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, data_loader, device, epoch, print_freq)
      7     lr_scheduler.step()
      8 

/content/drive/MyDrive/universidad/t3/MinneApple/utility/engine.py in train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, data_loader, device, epoch, print_freq)
     41             print("Loss is {}, stopping training".format(loss_value))
     42             print(loss_dict_reduced)
---> 43             sys.exit(1)
     44 
     45         optimizer.zero_grad()

SystemExit: 1
```